# 1996 Oldsmobile Ninety Eight: door handle/lock dented in, stuck shut

Tags: locks, door, oldsmobile, dent

**[Edit] Assume all the latch linkages are broken. I've removed some of the inner door panel, but there is not much room to work, as I have to keep my wrist bent. Is there a technique for opening or even removing the door if the linkage is somehow broken *right* at the lock itself?**

---

How can I get this sucker open? The handle/latch assembly has been dented in by a minor accident, and the door is stuck shut. The handle has full range of motion, but the internals are jammed somehow.

Here's an exterior look at the dented-in handle assembly..

[image]

I was able to remove the interior handle/lock, exposing the rod. Lifting up on the rod does nothing, even with aggressive force. I think I get resistance in the last %15 of the range of motion.

[image]

Fortunately I can still get the window down. I managed to lasso the lever arm and pull up, hard, but it's useless. I don't feel any resistance either, which makes me think the metal linkage arm is just flexing, but not actuating the lock for some reason..

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Finally, and it's difficult to photograph, but I have *some* of the interior door panel pulled away. It's enough to see more of the linkages. I'm *certain* I'm teasing the linkages in the proper direction, but no amount of strength on the linkage rods nor any amount of pushing I can muster is opening this door.

Is it possible the linkages are broken *right* where they meet the locking mechanism on the frame? If so, and realizing I can't contort my wrist or elbow enough to feel around near the frame, is there any other way to get this door open at this point? Any ideas what a body shop might try in the even of a T-boned door, etc?

Comment: see if you can get eyes on the latch it self sometimes things like this require a long screw driver and a bit of force to get unstuck.

Comment: Hi @Ben, thanks for the nod. I was able to get some of the inner door panel pulled away, but there is barely enough room to get my hand in there, and certainly not enough to get good angles in many directions. I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you describing some way to get the door open by *entirely* bypassing the linkage arms? ..I think that's what I need to accomplish at this point.

Comment: I'm guessing the locking part of the latch is stuck in a half locked position. Generally you can look at the latch from the top and use a long rod to push or pull the locking lever one way or another.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Well I *think* I tried that with the rope in my third pic. I could tell which way to direct the linkage rods by watching the effect applied by the handle, so I lassoed the rod and gave it some aggressive tugs upward to no effect. I'm afraid the issue is right near the frame, somehow, but since I can't open the door to remove the inner panel, I can't remove the inner panel enough to properly inspect the issue near the frame. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If it's really broken in the latch and using a rod doesn't work you either have to remove the inner door panel (by force) and break the latch or remove the rear door and cut the striker on the front door. You may even be able to remove the B pillar and drill the bolts that hold the striker with a 90° drill.

Comment: More than likely the lock linkage has popped off and the latch is still in the locked position, which would be why it doesn't want to come unlatched. If I could suggest, you may want to pull the other side apart to see where everything is clearly located and connected. This may help you understand the problem side, which will ultimately spell a way for you to get it open. Just a thought.